# com.facebook.sdk.core error 8 on like/comment

Tags: ios, facebook

I have approved all permission `public_profile`, `user_posts`, `email`, `user_friends`, `user_location`. Also made app to public (live) from facebook settings.

I am able to like/comment from admin fb account. But, getting error:

> the operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)

when I like/comment from other facebook account.

I am using `v2.4` api, `swift` and `ios9`.
Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.facebook.sdk.core error 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684648/com-facebook-sdk-core-error-8)